# homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

I need a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$

So i took $f$ and $h$, and need to demonstrate $h\circ f$ is the homeomorphism that i need.

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\} \rightarrow S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}$

$f(x) = (\frac{x}{\|x\|}, \|x\|)$, is injective, surjective and continuous.

The inverse is:
$f^{-1}(x,y) = xy$ and it is also continuous. Therefore $f$ is a homeomorphism.

$h: S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$

$h(x,y) = (x, \log(y))$ and $h^{-1}(x,y) = (x, e^y)$ both continuous.

so $h \circ f:  \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \rightarrow S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism.

is this all correct?

Can i generalize to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow S^{n}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. It is just fine.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb{R}_+$, you mean $(0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, yes

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can i generalize to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow S^{n}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes: $x\mapsto\left(\frac x{\lVert x\rVert},\log\lVert x\rVert\right)$.